# compare values in the same coloumn in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

i have table like that in mysql:

```
from value to
1     45   2 
3     20   4
2     45   1
4     20   3
```

I want to check values 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 has the same values .

can you give me some example not exact query?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I wanted to help but didn't get your question. Can you clarify a bit what you're looking for?

Comment: i wan to check from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1 has the same values you may see in the table they have same value but i want to be sure for other examples

Comment: okay, so you have the table `SOMETABLE` that has that very structure? `from` `value` and `to`, right? The primary column would be `from` and you wanted to check if 2 to 1 is 45 as well as 1 to 2? Further question: isn't it possible to insert duplicate values in this table? If it's possible to insert more than a 1 to 2 row, then you may end up in a bit of a confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `exists`.  This will return all the instances where the values are not the same:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.from = t.to and
                        t2.to = t.from and
                        t2.value = t.value
                 );
```

Comment: Have we been guaranteed that the `(from,to)` tuple is unique? What if there exist rows `(2,45,1)` **and** `(2,42,1)`. Just because we find an inverse row with a matching value, that doesn't mean that there isn't also an inverse row that has a value that doesn't match.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . I don't disagree.  Perhaps the OP can clarify what s/he wants.

Comment: +1 I omitted a mention (in my previous comment) that this query DOES return an appropriate resultset for the sample data shown. My previous comment was concerning other possible data that was _not_ shown in the  sample data, and my usual caution about making unwarranted assumptions about uniqueness et al.

Comment: i only have one table what is the t2 in this situtation

Comment: @user3297904 . . . It is called a table alias and an important part of the SQL language.  It allows you to refer to the same table multiple times in a query, for self-joins and correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to group by the value. Then you can count if the `from` and  `to` columns have the right values. If the count is greater than zero for both conditions then you have met your requirement.

Hover over to see the query

> select value
>  from your_table
>  group by value
>  having sum(`from` = 1 and `to` = 2) = 1
>  and sum(`from` = 2 and `to` = 1) = 1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will return a row where at least one corresponding inverse row does not have a "matching" value:

```
SELECT a.from, a.to, a.value, b.value
  FROM mytable a
  JOIN mytable b
    ON b.from = a.to
   AND b.to = a.from
 WHERE a.from < a.to
   AND NOT a.value <=> b.value
```

(NOTE: this query doesn't identify rows that do not have an inverse row, it only identifies rows where an inverse row exists in the table, but that inverse row has a different `value`.)